# Schematic of neural lineage tree and position of Choroid Plexus cells

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I am trying to understand which are the different type of progenitors in the human brain and I am currently following [this schematic](https://www.abcam.com/neuroscience/neural-markers-guide).

My question is, are Choroid Plexus cells progenitors to Radial Glia (is [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5319247/) basically stating that they might work as progenitors)? Otherwise, do they reside out of the provided neural lineage tree? I am aware of their functions related to CSF.

Otherwise, do you have reference papers on neural lineage tree that you can share?